# Replacing the "person" that links as contacts icon with another icon in MS Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, add-in

I was assigned for a client that needs and Outlook add-in and apparently, I don't know where to start but the client said that he wants that dollar icon to replace the person icon to create another function. I was wondering if that's possible, I mean, that has been pre-defined by the Microsoft team and they are the ones that have the source code. How am I supposed to do that?

PS. Sorry for bad english

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What icon do you need to replace? And where?

Comment: sorry I cant put up a image yet. But what I meant is the person icon that links you to Contacts page.It is between the Calendar button and Task button. Bottom left of Outlook 2016. Along with the Mail, Notes and Folders buttons

Comment: I found the answer man. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I think I figured this out a little. I found a documentation of Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692173%28office.14%29.aspx).